# Identical twins have the same DNA and blood-types, right? But different fingerprints? Why is that? Same for clones?

Tags: blood-type, dna, fingerprint

Identical twins have the same DNA and blood-types, right? But different fingerprints? Why do they have different finger-prints? What gene or part of our body signals what our fingerprint will look like?

Would the same situation be true of clones if there were to be human clones? Or would their fingerprints match too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fingerprints are formed semi-randomly as the foetus develops in the womb and are affected by such things as chance fluctuations of hormone levels. Similarly, the pattern of freckles and moles on the skin is caused by random mutations and will vary between identical twins.

Identical twins are 'clones' of one another. Their fingerprints are similar but not identical. ... Fingerprints form patterns the same way frost on a window forms patterns -- due to physical forces and conditions, not due to DNA programming.

Yes, clones have fingerprints. No, they wouldn't be exactly like their original: fingerprints are influenced by in-utero and epigenetic factors, not just by the DNA. A clone's fingerprints would be very much alike its progenitor (and some features would be nearly identical), but not the same.

http://www.sciencefocus.com/qa/why-do-identical-twins-have-different-fingerprints

https://www.quora.com/Will-a-human-and-his-her-clone-have-the-same-fingerprints

Comment: Thanks, Prince, you're answering all sorts of questions lately! I appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

> Identical twins have the same DNA and blood-types, right?

Sort of. It is more complicated than that. DNA mutates at a rate of around 1 in 10,000 cell divisions. Some of those mutations will happens very early in development. Because of which it isn't uncommon for one twin to have different DNA based health conditions than the other. Identical twins usually have enough differences in their DNA that you can find a few legitimate differences in the raw output that services like 23andMe.com provide. If both twins have their Exomes sequenced there is usually enough differences to settle paternity and criminal DNA evidence issues. It has only reached a price to be realistic to do so in the last few years. There is even one company that provides DNA testing for twin issues.

https://www.wired.com/2014/12/genetic-test-distinguishes-identical-twins-may-used-court-first-time/

> But different fingerprints?

DNA will typically give twins the same type of fingerprints. But the exact shape is determined by environmental factors. 
http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2011/02/identical-twins-dont-have-identical-fingerprints-even-from-birth/